# In "Desolation of Smaug", why were Sauron's legions of orcs dispatched before Smaug had fallen?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Why, in *The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug* would Sauron send his legions to Erebor before Smaug had fallen. It couldn't possibly be to negotiate with him. As powerful as Azog is in these films, I'm sure Smaug would just say no and eat him.

Comment: Because the movie decided to add weird stuff that doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: Haha gotta agree with you their, pj hobbit film just dont add up im still annoyed about the whole nazgul tombs thing

Comment: I can't recall much of the film. But in the books, Gandalf wanted Smaug out of the way because he thought it was likely he'd side with Sauron. So it isn't absurd that the Orcs were sent to negotiate.

Comment: If you are talking about the orcs that were in the Battle of the Five Armies, I don't think they were Sauron's orcs.

Comment: Is there actually any indication in the movie that Sauron was sending his Orcs to Erebor?  I don't recall such.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the films got several things wrong key to this story.

**Azog is not even alive at the time of *The Hobbit***. Azog was killed at the Battle of Azanulbizar in 2799, while the events of the films take place in 2941.

**The orcs at the battle of the five armies were not from Sauron**. They were primarily from Mount Gundabad and Moria, as well as small colonies throughout the Misty Mountains.

**Sauron was not openly very concerned with Erebor at the time**. Sauron's focus was in returning to Mordor, though these preparations were not as obvious to the Wise, and so Sauron easily withdrew from Dol Guldur and into Mordor when the White Council moved against him.

So to analyze this situation from the book point of view is impossible. And to analyze it from the films can only be done by chalking it up to "the needs of the screen".